# Why can't I draw a complete circle with arc() in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to draw a complex shape in Three.js using extruded arcs but they just didn't seem to be behaving properly. I don't know if I don't understand the API, but shouldn't this create a complete extruded circle of radius 100 centred at the origin?

```
var path = new THREE.Path();

path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.arc(0, 0, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);

var shape = path.toShapes(false, false);

var extrudeSettings = {
    amount : 20,
    steps : 1
};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Instead it draws a Pacman shape:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/0c3c1beb427ff2627b7b3d273a093ac4.png]

Here's the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c8shqzpn/

Comment: As a work-around, try an approach in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a more complicated path with arcs and it's failing miserably. If it can't do this simple test case of drawing a circle then there's no hope for it working correctly for my complicated path. The circle on that page seems to be using a quadratic path, which may work for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/19f7qssj/ - The path is closed when using quadratic curves, but it isn't a circle (as they can't be represented by quadratic bezier curves http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/) 

Probably good enough, though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/19f7qssj/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/c8shqzpn/1/

Comment: WestLangley, please post that as answer so I can accept it! I'm puzzled by why the current position forms part of the arc, it seems like the centre point, start angle, end angle and direction provided to arc() completely define the curve and the current position should be irrelevant?

Comment: @thenickdude you need more curves there http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?369672-Draw-a-circle-with-quadratic-bezier-curves&s=0b60c6e70c86babf3bc97000f8e48bb9&p=1977790&viewfull=1#post1977790

Comment: Well, now you know how to draw a pacman :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to create a circle shape so you can extrude it.

Whenever you draw an arc, it connects the start of the arc to the current point, so in your case, you have to use the `moveTo()` command to set the start point on the perimeter of the circle.

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();

shape.moveTo( circleRadius, 0 );
shape.absarc( 0, 0, circleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
```

three.js r.70

Comment: Thanks! Though curiously, if I do these two commands as a Path and then convert it to a Shape with path.toShapes(false, false), I still get the Pacman. It works if I just use Shape and don't use the path at all.

Comment: I linked to a fiddle in my comment above that shows you how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues drawing 3/4 of a circle and extruding it and adding the result (a THREE.Mesh) to the screen. The circle seemed to miss a segment. Adding `moveTo( x, y )` where x, y are coordinates of the beginning of the arc solved the issue. I used this code:

```
var extrudeSettings = {
    bevelEnabled: false,
    steps: 1,
    amount: 2
};

var shape = new THREE.Shape();
var circleRadius = 4;

// THIS LINE SOLVES THE ISSUE 
shape.moveTo( 0, -circleRadius );

shape.absarc( 0, 0, circleRadius, 0, 1.5 * Math.PI, false );
shape.lineTo( 0, 0 );
shape.closePath();

var geometry = shape.extrude( extrudeSettings );

scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() ) );
```

First my mesh looked like this:

[image: First my mesh looked like this]

After adding `shape.moveTo( 0, -circleRadius );` the mesh looked like this:

[image: after adding <code>shape.moveTo( 0, -circleRadius );</code>the mesh looked like this]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be solved if you multiply Math.PI bye 2.1, instead of 2?